# Kiosk mode in wxpython?

Tags: python, wxpython, mode, kiosk

Is there a way to create a 'kiosk mode' in wxpython under Windows (98 - 7) where the application disables you from breaking out of the app using Windows keys, alt-tab, alt-f4, and ctrl+alt+delete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an application could do that it would make a great denial-of-service attack on the machine.

In particular Ctrl+Alt+Delete is the [Secure Attention Sequence](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780332(WS.10).aspx).  Microsoft goes to great lengths to insure that when the user hits those keys, they switch to a secure desktop that they can be confident that the logon box is the *real* Windows logon and not a counterfeit.

What you need to look at isn't functions that your application can call, but System Administration options that allow an Administrator to configure a machine for limited use.  These exist, but it's more a question for Super User than for Stack Overflow.

This should get you started
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372139(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

wxPython alone cannot be done with that.

You need to do Low Level Keyboard Hook with C/C++ or with equivalent ctypes, for

Windows keys, alt-tab, alt-f4,

but Ctrl-Alt-Del, I don't think so for Windows XP and above.